# An anime about a samurai who has extended canines

Tags: inuyasha

There's an anime I used to watch about 7 years ago on animax.
I cannot recall it's name.
Some information:

- It was about a samurai.
- He wore a red dress that covered his full body and draped from his arms.
- He has extended canines.
- He sports a long grey (or white) hair.
- He says something (rather yells) that changes his look or something like that.
- He has a hot girlfriend. ;)
- He had an enormous sword.More specifically, a sabre.
- 2 or 3 seasons of this anime aired. There were a couple of movies too.
- I remember Animax dedicating a whole weekend to this anime.

If anyone can give me any suggestions, it'd be appreciable. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the anime you are looking for is [Inuyasha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inuyasha). The anime has lots of episodes, aired on Animax, and he has fangs, red drapes and shouts.

[image]

Fangs, Check

[image]

Sabre kind of Gigantic Sword, Check

[image]

And long red drapes, Check

[image]

The only problem is that his girlfriend does not look that hot to me.

Comment: Yeah... I was a child then... I agree with you now... She ain't so hot... It's the right answer... I've been trying to remember the name for maybe a year... Thanks so much... 

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you were looking for Inuyasha - but he is not a samurai.  He's a Hanyo, or half-demon, and his robes are not the samurai kimono and hakama. As I recall, the robes are made of fireproof silk of some kind; it's been ten years or so since I saw the series so I don't remember exactly what the material comes from.

Comment: Let's not be too technical...

Comment: Not meaning to be technical, just accurate.  Samurai were real people; demons generally aren't :)

Comment: You are right bro... No offense...